# Valid JSON feed | blank page

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp, getjson

Here is my jsonp feed: http://www.letheatredelorient.fr/saison/data.jsonp (JSONLint valid)

Here is my getJSON script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("http://www.letheatredelorient.fr/saison/data.jsonp?callback=", function (data)             {
$.each(data.Items, function (i, node) {
var title = node.titre;
$("#myTitle").html(title);
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myTitle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's really simple. But, it gets the feed, but it doesn't parse it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var title = node.node.titre;
```

In your code the node is the Item object, the node is in that, is this a little clearer?

```
$.getJSON("http://www.letheatredelorient.fr/saison/data.jsonp?callback=", function (data) {
    $.each(data.Items, function (i, item) {
        //For each item in Items
        var title = item.node.titre;
        $("#myTitle").html(title);
    });
});
```

This is your json, I've added comments, you're looping through items which contain node:

```
{
    "Items": [
        -item{
            "node": {
                "titre": "La Faculté",
                "image": "http://www.letheatredelorient.fr/sites/default/files/imagecache/130/saison/spectacles/faculte/photos/faculte-web2calainfonteray.jpg"
            }
        },
        -item{
            "node": {
                "titre": "Nouveau Roman",
                "image": "http://www.letheatredelorient.fr/sites/default/files/imagecache/130/saison/spectacles/nouveau-roman/photos/1210-nouveauroman-04cjeanlouisfernandez.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you ! It works, but I try to understand, why there is a second level of "node".

Comment: Because you aren't looping through nodes, you're looping through their container objects - I'll amend the above